# Como destruir las preferencias al salir de la aplicación (SharedPreferences en Android Studio)

Tags: mysql, android-studio, recyclerview, sharedpreferences

Buen día, me explico.
Actualmente me encuentro trabajando con preferencias, estas preferencias me ayudan en el funcionamiento de un carrito de compras implementado en Android Studio utilizando RecyclerView y obteniendo los productos desde la base de datos `MySQL` Las preferencias las estoy usando para poder guaradar el contador del carrito de compras, hasta este punto todo esta bien no hay ningun problema, pues el usuario mientras se encuentra navegando dentro de la aplicación el estado del carrito de compras se mantiene de forma correcta, el problema radica cuando salgo de la aplicación, osea cuando definitivamente la finalizo, una vez hago esto y vuelvo a entrar el estado del contador permanece activo **Sin embargo yo no quiero que el carrito se encuentre activo cuendo el usuario finalice lo que quiero es que todos los estados de l aplicacion se destruyan y cuando el usuario inicie otra vez, todos los estados esten como nuevos como si no han sido tocados ni una vez, en este caso es el carrito de compras**

***"Esta es la actividad donde guardo el estado del carrito"***

```
public void saveData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(TEXT, tvCantProductos.getText().toString());
    editor.clear().apply();
    editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Datos guardados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void loadData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    text = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT, "0");
}

public void updateViews(){
    tvCantProductos.setText(text);
}
```

> El método "saveData" es invocado dentro de un botón que se encuentra dentro de la clase cuando yo doy click a dicho botón este guarda el estado del contador (En realidad son 2 botones los que necesito para guardar el estado).

Al final tengo una `Activity` llamada "Pantalla final" esta tiene dos botones uno llamado "Realizar mas compras" y otro llamado "Cerrar sesión" en este caso yo quiero destruir todos los estados cuando cierre la sesión.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar los valores de la preferencia , puedes usar el mismo método con el que guardas los valores, pero en este caso recibirá un valor:

```
public void saveData(String valor){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(TEXT, valor);
    editor.apply();

   if (valor != null && !valor.isEmpty() && !valor.equals("null")){
     Toast.makeText(this, "Datos guardados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Datos eliminados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

}
```

de esta forma llamarías el método cuando finalices tu aplicación, guardando el valor "0" que veo es el que usas para inicializar tu carrito.

```
saveData("0");
```

Comment: Excelente, me ha servido muy bien, muchas gracias!